# Change Label.Text in any step in the loop

Tags: c#

I want in this code in the any step label show the Number of that step.
In the my code just show last number in the label!

I also Label.Invalidate() the done, but do not work.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<100)
        {
            i++;
            label1.Text = string.Format("Step is :{0}", i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } 
   }
```

Comment: You're telling the UI thread to sleep, so you won't be able to see it update until the last step after it's slept the 100th time.

Comment: What platform? winforms? webforms? wpf? silverlight? xna? Surface? cf? MonoTouch? MonoDroid?

Answer (score 12):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx

Invoke `Update` after setting text, it will help you. But of course you should consider background threads.

```
label1.Text = string.Format("Step is :{0}", i);
label1.Update();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your loop is being executed on the UI thread, the UI thread is blocked and is not able to update the text until the loop is completed.

You might look into using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) component and it's [patterns](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/LivMic/BGWorker07032007000515AM/BGWorker.aspx) to do your loop's work instead.

Comment: Oh. Assumed WinForms, but similar answers apply to WPF/Silverlight etc.